# Data Mining prediction Server Operation has been cancelled

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2008, data-mining

I will appriciate the help if anyone has encountered the problem before or has an idea how to resolve it. I am trying to create an data mining with visual studio 2008. And I am almost to the end.

[image]

and when I press the Run button I get the following errors.
I tried different version for the server name from (local) to the server of System Analyses of SQL Server 2008R2
[image]

If someone can help me it would be great. Thank all.

Comment: Did you read the error message?  "Login failed for user .... Cannot open database AdventureWorks2008R2 ...", etc.  Analysis services can't connect to the sql database.